# How to pass a dateTime parameter of a particular format in inputMask in JSF?

Tags: mysql, jsf, datepicker, date-formatting, input-mask

I need to display a date in Input Mask that I retrieved from the database. The date from the database is in the following format :

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

which is a string.

I need it to be displayed in the textbox as :

```
MM/dd/yyyy
```

I used the code as below,

```
<p:inputMask mask="99/99/9999" value="#{iterator.displayValue}" id="ObjectDate"/>
```

My Bean value from the database is : Fri Mar 31 00:00:00 IST 2045. But the value displayed in the text box is : 31/00/0000. It is not recognizing the format correctly. Moreover if I retrieved the value as Date object, it works fine. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the date is stored in the database as datetime, use this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(myDate, "%d/%l/%Y") AS formattedDate FROM myTable_
```

**UPDATE:**

Your current select statement is

```
SELECT IFNULL(concat(DATE_FORMAT(MAX(MY_DATE), '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s '),
             @@system_time_zone,DATE_FORMAT(MAX(MY_DATE),' %Y')),'')
       AS VALUES, FROM table_name where id = some_id;
```

Replace it with:

```
SELECT IFNULL(concat(DATE_FORMAT(MAX(MY_DATE), '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s '),
             @@system_time_zone,DATE_FORMAT(MAX(MY_DATE),' %Y')),'')
       AS VALUES,
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(MY_DATE), "%d/%l/%Y") AS formattedDate
       FROM table_name where id = some_id;
```

This way you will still have `VALUES` for whatever you are using it now. And you can use `formattedDate` to diplay.

Comment: But I get the date in EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy format from the Database as a String. It is not displayed correctly in InputMask as 99/99/9999.

Comment: What is the SELECT statement you use to get the info from the database?

Comment: SELECT IFNULL(concat(DATE_FORMAT(MAX(MY_DATE), '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s '),@@system_time_zone,DATE_FORMAT(MAX(MY_DATE),' %Y')),'') AS VALUES, 


FROM table_name where id = some_id;